# Vert.x: can I mix a wildcard route with an explicit route?

Tags: swagger-ui, vert.x

I want to host [Swagger UI](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/usage/installation.md#plain-old-htmlcssjs-standalone) as static content using Vert.x. The `swagger-initializer.js` needs the spec somewhere on the server and I want it to be in `/api/swagger-ui` as well, so I can define the spec in `swagger-initializer.js` as

```
window.onload = function() {
  window.ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
    url: "petstore.yaml",
    dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
    deepLinking: true,
    presets: [
      SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis,
      SwaggerUIStandalonePreset
    ],
    plugins: [
      SwaggerUIBundle.plugins.DownloadUrl
    ],
    layout: "StandaloneLayout"
  });
};
```

It works perfectly like this

```
Router.router(vertx).route("/api/swagger-ui/petstore.json").handler(StaticHandler.create("path/to/petstore.json"));
Router.router(vertx).route("/api/swagger-ui/*").handler(StaticHandler.create("path/to/swagger-ui"));
```

serving Swagger UI together with the provided spec.

But I wonder if there are any side effects by mixing a wildcard with an explicit route?

Are there any resources if this is good practice and it doesn't just work by coincidence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fine, because by default routes are matched in the order they are added to the router.

When a request arrives, the router will step through each route and check if it matches, if it matches then the handler for that route will be called.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you have any reference for this?

Comment: See https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web/java/#_route_order